# 2 separate facebook pixels - one integrated into shopify, one on GTM - How to make it work?

Tags: facebook, shopify, google-tag-manager

I have a fairly unique business model in which I need to use a retail partner to sell my produce because licensing is difficult.  They have to collect money and transfer it to supplies on my behalf so my product must be sold on their site.

They have their own acquisition campaigns running through facebook and therefor have a facebook pixel passing data for those ads and it's directly integrated into shopify.  Our products end up just being another sku on their site but we would like to also support those with facebook ads so would need to have our pixel as well.  Unfortunately shopify only allows one tracking code from facebook.

Would there be any issue is setting our facebook pixel up on Google Tag Manager (we have the container across their site) and expecting it to fire in parallel with the pixel that they have integrated into shopify?

Followup, same scenario for Google Analytics, Google Adwords, etc.

Thanks!

Comment: There won't be any issues with implementing multiple fb pixels. Same with GA and adwords.

Comment: Thanks for confirming!  Because we are working off another team's site, we want to make sure we're extra double buttoned up here and don't cause any errors or hurt their current tracking in any way.